# hiveserver2 on windows 'File Not Found' and hangs

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed hive 1.1.0 on windows 7 32-bit, I can use hive console to create table, query etc, and I can see those were written to hdfs://users/hive/warehouse

But i'm not able to start hiveserver2. After entering the command, it hangs. Below are the console print, please help, thanks!

```
C:\hive\bin>hive --service hiveserver2
File Not Found
File Not Found
File Not Found
File Not Found
File Not Found
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j
12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar!/o
rg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf
4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

hive.log

```
2015-06-02 15:38:46,920 WARN  [main]: common.LogUtils (LogUtils.java:logConfigLocation(140)) - DEPRECATED: Ignoring hive-default.xml found on the CLASSPATH at /C:/hive/conf/hive-default.xml
2015-06-02 15:38:47,014 INFO  [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveStringUtils.java:startupShutdownMessage(662)) - STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting HiveServer2
STARTUP_MSG:   host = NWT1302004/10.192.37.175
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.1.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = too long, remove, otherwise can't save question
STARTUP_MSG:   build = git://localhost.localdomain/Users/noland/workspaces/hive-apache/hive -r 3b87e226d9f2ff5d69385ed20704302cffefab21; compiled by 'noland' on Wed Feb 18 16:06:08 PST 2015
************************************************************/
2015-06-02 15:38:47,030 INFO  [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:startHiveServer2(303)) - Starting HiveServer2
2015-06-02 15:38:49,409 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:newRawStore(575)) - 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:38:49,613 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:initialize(269)) - ObjectStore, initialize called
2015-06-02 15:39:05,190 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getPMF(350)) - Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2015-06-02 15:39:12,603 INFO  [main]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(132)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2015-06-02 15:39:12,603 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(252)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:39:14,678 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(649)) - Added admin role in metastore
2015-06-02 15:39:14,678 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(658)) - Added public role in metastore
2015-06-02 15:39:14,958 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:addAdminUsers_core(698)) - No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
2015-06-02 15:39:16,767 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created local directory: C:/Users/46172/AppData/Local/Temp/335c6071-cebd-40b8-b4c3-4d77d3e81d48_resources
2015-06-02 15:39:16,798 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/46172/335c6071-cebd-40b8-b4c3-4d77d3e81d48
2015-06-02 15:39:16,798 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created local directory: C:/Users/46172/AppData/Local/Temp/46172/335c6071-cebd-40b8-b4c3-4d77d3e81d48
2015-06-02 15:39:16,798 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/46172/335c6071-cebd-40b8-b4c3-4d77d3e81d48/_tmp_space.db
2015-06-02 15:39:16,798 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(488)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,262 INFO  [main]: service.CompositeService (SessionManager.java:initOperationLogRootDir(132)) - Operation log root directory is created: C:\Users\46172\AppData\Local\Temp\46172\operation_logs
2015-06-02 15:39:21,329 INFO  [main]: service.CompositeService (SessionManager.java:createBackgroundOperationPool(89)) - HiveServer2: Background operation thread pool size: 100
2015-06-02 15:39:21,329 INFO  [main]: service.CompositeService (SessionManager.java:createBackgroundOperationPool(91)) - HiveServer2: Background operation thread wait queue size: 100
2015-06-02 15:39:21,330 INFO  [main]: service.CompositeService (SessionManager.java:createBackgroundOperationPool(94)) - HiveServer2: Background operation thread keepalive time: 10 seconds
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:init(89)) - Service:OperationManager is inited.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:init(89)) - Service:SessionManager is inited.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:init(89)) - Service:CLIService is inited.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:init(89)) - Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is inited.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:init(89)) - Service:HiveServer2 is inited.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:OperationManager is started.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:SessionManager is started.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:CLIService is started.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:initialize(269)) - ObjectStore, initialize called
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(132)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(252)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: get_databases: default
2015-06-02 15:39:21,433 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases: default  
2015-06-02 15:39:21,559 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: Shutting down the object store...
2015-06-02 15:39:21,559 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=Shutting down the object store...   
2015-06-02 15:39:21,559 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: Metastore shutdown complete.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,559 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=Metastore shutdown complete.    
2015-06-02 15:39:21,559 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is started.
2015-06-02 15:39:21,559 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:HiveServer2 is started.
2015-06-02 15:50:25,794 WARN  [main]: common.LogUtils (LogUtils.java:logConfigLocation(140)) - DEPRECATED: Ignoring hive-default.xml found on the CLASSPATH at /C:/hive/conf/hive-default.xml
2015-06-02 15:50:25,856 INFO  [main]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(852)) - 
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/C:/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
2015-06-02 15:50:26,152 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:newRawStore(575)) - 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:50:26,199 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:initialize(269)) - ObjectStore, initialize called
2015-06-02 15:50:29,569 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getPMF(350)) - Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2015-06-02 15:50:34,252 INFO  [main]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(132)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2015-06-02 15:50:34,252 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(252)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:50:34,424 WARN  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:checkSchema(6599)) - Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0
2015-06-02 15:50:34,830 WARN  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getDatabase(548)) - Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
2015-06-02 15:50:35,282 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(649)) - Added admin role in metastore
2015-06-02 15:50:35,329 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(658)) - Added public role in metastore
2015-06-02 15:50:35,454 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:addAdminUsers_core(698)) - No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
2015-06-02 15:50:35,750 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created local directory: C:/Users/46172/AppData/Local/Temp/bc6dabf4-b50d-4a04-9677-774846caca49_resources
2015-06-02 15:50:35,750 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/46172/bc6dabf4-b50d-4a04-9677-774846caca49
2015-06-02 15:50:35,766 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created local directory: C:/Users/46172/AppData/Local/Temp/46172/bc6dabf4-b50d-4a04-9677-774846caca49
2015-06-02 15:50:35,766 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/46172/bc6dabf4-b50d-4a04-9677-774846caca49/_tmp_space.db
2015-06-02 15:50:35,766 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(488)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
2015-06-02 15:50:37,934 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: get_all_databases
2015-06-02 15:50:37,934 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases   
2015-06-02 15:50:37,950 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
2015-06-02 15:50:37,950 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=* 
2015-06-02 15:50:44,623 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=Driver.run from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,623 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,623 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,716 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,732 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: version

2015-06-02 15:50:44,982 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(861)) - FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'version' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'version' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

2015-06-02 15:50:44,982 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=compile start=1433231444623 end=1433231444982 duration=359 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,982 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,982 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1433231444982 end=1433231444982 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,982 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:50:44,982 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1433231444982 end=1433231444982 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-06-02 15:51:03,720 WARN  [main]: common.LogUtils (LogUtils.java:logConfigLocation(140)) - DEPRECATED: Ignoring hive-default.xml found on the CLASSPATH at /C:/hive/conf/hive-default.xml
2015-06-02 15:51:03,783 INFO  [main]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(852)) - 
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/C:/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
2015-06-02 15:51:04,487 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:newRawStore(575)) - 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:51:04,518 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:initialize(269)) - ObjectStore, initialize called
2015-06-02 15:51:07,888 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:getPMF(350)) - Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2015-06-02 15:51:09,666 INFO  [main]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(132)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
2015-06-02 15:51:09,666 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(252)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2015-06-02 15:51:09,838 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(649)) - Added admin role in metastore
2015-06-02 15:51:09,838 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:createDefaultRoles_core(658)) - Added public role in metastore
2015-06-02 15:51:09,869 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:addAdminUsers_core(698)) - No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
2015-06-02 15:51:10,481 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created local directory: C:/Users/46172/AppData/Local/Temp/320de2e6-0f30-408b-b8f1-e65869a939ea_resources
2015-06-02 15:51:10,496 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/46172/320de2e6-0f30-408b-b8f1-e65869a939ea
2015-06-02 15:51:10,496 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created local directory: C:/Users/46172/AppData/Local/Temp/46172/320de2e6-0f30-408b-b8f1-e65869a939ea
2015-06-02 15:51:10,496 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(586)) - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/46172/320de2e6-0f30-408b-b8f1-e65869a939ea/_tmp_space.db
2015-06-02 15:51:10,496 INFO  [main]: session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(488)) - No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
2015-06-02 15:51:11,027 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: get_all_databases
2015-06-02 15:51:11,027 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_all_databases   
2015-06-02 15:51:11,042 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: get_functions: db=default pat=*
2015-06-02 15:51:11,042 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_functions: db=default pat=* 
2015-06-02 16:12:31,212 INFO  [Thread-6]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:stop(269)) - Shutting down HiveServer2
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-2]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveStringUtils.java:run(680)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down HiveServer2 at NWT1302004/10.192.37.175
************************************************************/
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-7]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:run(98)) - Started ThriftBinaryCLIService on port 10000 with 5...500 worker threads
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-6]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:stop(138)) - Thrift server has stopped
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-6]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is stopped.
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-6]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:OperationManager is stopped.
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-6]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:SessionManager is stopped.
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-6]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:CLIService is stopped.
2015-06-02 16:12:31,228 INFO  [Thread-6]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:HiveServer2 is stopped.
```

Comment: @RamananR, thanks for the reply, i found derby.log and added to the question, not sure if this is the log you asked. if there're other log files, please let me know, i'll post in question, thanks!

Comment: @RamananR, i found hive.log, it's added in question

Answer (score 0):

I used mysql as metastore, the hiveserver2 is able to start now:

```
2015-06-03 10:37:36,863 INFO  [main]: metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql (MetaStoreDirectSql.java:<init>(132)) - Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
2015-06-03 10:37:36,863 INFO  [main]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:setConf(252)) - Initialized ObjectStore
2015-06-03 10:37:36,879 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: get_databases: default
2015-06-03 10:37:36,879 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_databases: default  
2015-06-03 10:37:36,910 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: Shutting down the object store...
2015-06-03 10:37:36,910 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=Shutting down the object store...   
2015-06-03 10:37:36,910 INFO  [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(732)) - 0: Metastore shutdown complete.
2015-06-03 10:37:36,910 INFO  [main]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(358)) - ugi=46172   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=Metastore shutdown complete.    
2015-06-03 10:37:36,910 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is started.
2015-06-03 10:37:36,926 INFO  [main]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:start(104)) - Service:HiveServer2 is started.
```